# 'vector iterators incompatible'

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, std

```
std::vector<Enemy*>::iterator it;
for(it;it!=tracked.end();it++){
    (*it)->update(timeSinceLastFrame);
}
```

`tracked` is the vector:

```
std::vector<Enemy*>
```

Why am I getting this error? (please say if I haven't included enough details)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You never initialized the iterator.

```
for(std::vector<Enemy*>::iterator it = tracked.begin();it!=tracked.end();it++){
    (*it)->update(timeSinceLastFrame);
}
```

Many implementations (such as VC++, which you appear to be using) perform checks in debug to make sure that when two iterators are compared, they belong to the same object. A default constructed iterator does not belong to any particular instance, and as such the `it != tracked.end()` check will fail with that error.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't initialized `it`. Try this:

```
std::vector<Enemy*>::iterator it;
for(it=tracked.begin();it!=tracked.end();it++){
    (*it)->update(timeSinceLastFrame);
}
```